# How to avoid "bash: q: command not found" every time I 'su'?

Tags: bash, su

Every time I `su` from root to another user on a CentOS system, it displays:

> bash: q: command not found"

before giving me the prompt.

How to fix this?

Should I comment line

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

from vi /etc/sudoers ?

(ps: solution in [When I run "sudo su" I get --bash: command not found for everything](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216882/when-i-run-sudo-su-i-get-bash-command-not-found-for-everything) did not work...)

Comment: Sounds like some shell initialization script has a stray `q` in it that the shell tries to run as a command.

Comment: Like maybe /etc/profile or something.

Comment: (i'm not very into linux know how) but there is no letter 'q' even on /etc/profile

Comment: First: Are you running bash? Try: echo "$SHELL $BASH $PATH" Post output in your question. Next: what user are you `su`ing to: root?. Then, if actually using bash, try to find any q in either of this files `~/.bashrc ~/.profile` (there are others, but lets start with those two), try: `grep "q" ~/.bashrc profile`.

Comment: sorontar is correct that the two files (s)he lists are important. Can you first check that `su - someotheruser` gives you the same error about `q`, and then add a line `set -x` as the first line of `/etc/profile`, repeat the `su - someotheruser` and add the output to the question.

Comment: basically it gives the error when I ssh to the server already (on my local bash_profile I just have "alias srv2="ssh root@178.xxx.xxx.xx" so is not coming from the local). And also gives the error for any other user. And the output ssh to the server after adding set -x its in https://codeshare.io/aVDO62

Comment: results of commands I'm not allowed to post so its in https://codeshare.io/5vBNk5

Answer (score 5):

From your post of `bash -x`:

```
++ . /etc/bashrc
+++ '[' '\s-\v\$ ' ']'
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ case $TERM in
+++ '[' -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ']'
+++ PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" \
    "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
+++ q
-bash: q: command not found
```

So, there is a line with the letter `q` inside `/etc/.bashrc` after the line that sets the variable `PROMPT_COMMAND`. As it seems to be some stray text you can erase it.

You should edit the `/etc/.bashrc` inside the computer you `ssh'ed to`.

Comment: I think you mean `/etc/bashrc`, not `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @icarus And indeed, correct you are. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: yep, just checked the '~/.bashrc' for all users and there is no 'q' , it is in '/etc/bashrc' - Everything working smoothly - thank you!